# SSH into my Linux desktop computer from Chrome OS

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, cr-48

I have a CR 48 and would like to be able to access files on my Linux computer remotely. What's the best way to go about doing this? I've been reading all day and I think I'm more confused then when I started. Also, is SSH secured? How much control will I have remotely? And do I need to be in developer mode in Chrome OS to do this? Thanks!

Comment: "Is SSH secured?" It's the __Secure__ Shell. Running it is all dependent on whether or not Chrome OS has `ssh` installed, and you have access to a terminal.

Comment: OK, I sort of guessed that, maybe secured was the wrong word. I've had a few people tell me that it's not safe to use SSH to access files because it's unencrypted, is this even something I need to worry about?

Comment: No, there's a special file copier that uses SSH protocol called `scp`. I suggest you look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems [you don't need to](http://blog.binaryfever.com/developing-with-the-cr48) enable developer mode for SSH -

> Ctrl+Alt+T to get into a shell works
>   with out 'jailbreaking' your Cr-48. I
>   have yet to remove my dev tape (will
>   soon to dual boot Ubuntu) and have
>   been able to use the terminal to SSH.

To ssh, just type `ssh` at the terminal. However, there are few complaints about [it being limited](http://ejohn.org/blog/google-cr-48-for-coding/)..

> The only truly useful command is
>   ‘ssh’ and even then it’s painfully
>   limited. <s>There is no way to provide an
>   SSH key, for example (meaning that I
>   actually had to set up an account on
>   one of my servers with a password –
>   which is quite lame).</s>

[SSH keys are now supported](http://kaleb.hornsby.ws/comp/os/chrome/ssh-keys/).

Comment: No, SSH will only give you command-line access, so no GUI applications.

Comment: If you are in `crosh` and you type `ssh` and then `help`. It looks like you can use keys now.